# Inaccurate audio data plot with FFT (Python)

Tags: python, audio, signals, fft

I'm a beginner in Python and I'm trying to plot the full spectrum of an audio wav file. I was given a CSV data file that contains the frequency and magnitude as a reference. I have been figuring out the parameters to clone the plot but was unsuccessful. Since the audio file is in stereo format, I am using the second channel for the plotting.

Here's some info about the audio file:

- dtype:  float32
- Duration: 20 seconds
- Data Channels:  2
- No. of Channel One Sample:  512000
- No. of Channel Two Sample:  512000
- Sample Rate:  25600
- Sensitivity: 52.93mV / Pa

As you can see from the image below, the first plot is from the CSV data while the second plot is the end result. The end result is very noisy and messy despite having some characteristics from the CSV plot. Are there any ways I can do to get a close enough plot? Feel free to correct me if I'm wrong in my code. Thanks

[CSV Plot vs Result Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gVFXa.jpg)

```
if(len(signal.shape) > 1):
  # Second Signal
  fft = np.fft.fft(signal[1]) 
  magnitude = 20 * np.log10(np.abs(fft) / 2e-5)  # Convert to dB unit
  frequency = np.linspace(0, sr, len(magnitude))

  plt.figure(figsize=(25, 5))
  plt.semilogx(frequency, magnitude, 'b')
  plt.grid(which='major')
  plt.grid(which='minor', linestyle=':')
  plt.title('First Signal')
  plt.xlabel("Frequency (Hz)")
  plt.ylabel("SPL (dB)")

  plt.show()
```

I'm pretty sure the dB conversion is wrong :(

*Update: Instead of using normal FFT, I used Welch's method by Scipy. It's pretty close but could be optimized further.

```
x = data[1] * (2**15)  # scale signal to [-1.0 .. 1.0]
segment_size = sr
noverlap = segment_size / 2
f, Pxx = signal.welch(x,                        # signal
                  fs=sr,                    # sample rate
                  nperseg=segment_size,     # segment size
                  window='hann',         # window type to use
                  nfft=segment_size,        # num. of samples in FFT
                  detrend=False,            # remove DC part
                  scaling='spectrum',       # return power spectrum [V^2]
                  noverlap=noverlap)        # overlap between segments

ref = 2e-5   
p = librosa.power_to_db(Pxx, ref=ref) + 4.5 # add 4.5 dB for scale factor
```

[CSV Plot vs Result Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nHsOI.jpg)

Comment: From the DC frequency band , I think this may just be a problem with padding or windowing the data.

Comment: Hmm... how should I resolve it?

Comment: This question appears to be a mixture of programming but also understanding DSP in particular principles of data analysis using a Discrete Fourier Transform. In other words it may be casting the net a bit too wide for SO. You say you were given _CSV_ data, so I imagine this is for some kind of university course. If that is the case, I highly recommend you engage with the staff at your institute.